# Google Maps Markers clickable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

so I am relatively new to Jquery, JavaScript and the Google Maps API but I am slowly learning. I currently have a patch-job list work using this code:

```
            // Add marker to list
            $("<li />")
                .html('<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + array[i].venue + '<\/a>')
                // .html(array[i].venue)
                // .click(function(i) {
                //  myclick(i);
                // })
                .appendTo("#list");
```

And for your reference, this is myclick:

```
    function myclick(i) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], "click");
    }
```

My question is why is the commented out block working? When I load the [page](http://jsfiddle.net/rmKCj/) in JS fiddle, it doesn't work as it does in my browser, but I would like the commented out section to work. Why I want the commented out code to work is so that you can click anywhere in the box, not just on the words themselves.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You mean, why is the commented out block **not** working? Also, please refrain from asking us to download files to solve your problem — you should instead create a minimal replica of your example on an accessible **online** resource, like JSFiddle.

Comment: Got it going in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rmKCj/, but the links are not working at all